# AngularJS simple controller is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <title>Learning AngularJS</title>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" style="background: #eec; min-height:300px; margin-top: 15px;" ng-controller="SimpleController">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="woman in customer">{{ woman.name }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

JS (controller and data):

```
<script>
  function SimpleController($scope) {
    $scope.customer = [
      { name: 'Kamila', city: 'Opava' }, 
      { name: 'Nikola', city: 'Opočno' }, 
      { name: 'Jana', city: 'Pardubice' }, 
      { name: 'Martina', city: 'Hradec Kralove' }, 
      { name: 'Justýna', city: 'Chrudim' }
    ];
  };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Result my browser: `{{ woman.name }}` only

I do not know where is the mistake.

Answer (score 4):

You did not declare the app. 
Example:

```
<html ng-app="phonecatApp">
```

See details on [AngularJS example](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02)

Answer (score 2):

Please see here http://jsbin.com/vaweyu/1/edit

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
 <title>Learning AngularJS</title>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" style="background: #eec; min-height:300px; margin-top: 15px;" ng-controller="SimpleController">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="woman in customer">{{ woman.name }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);


   app.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.customer = [
          { name: 'Kamila', city: 'Opava' }, 
          { name: 'Nikola', city: 'Opočno' }, 
          { name: 'Jana', city: 'Pardubice' }, 
          { name: 'Martina', city: 'Hradec Kralove' }, 
          { name: 'Justýna', city: 'Chrudim' }
        ];
      });
```